# tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor builds unexpectedly bad model for a data with one feature

Tags: tensorflow, linear-regression, tflearn

I am building a simple linear regressor for the data from the [csv](http://%22https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/car/Davis.csv%22). Data includes weight and height values of some people. Overall learning process is very simple:

```
MAX_STEPS = 2000
# ...
features = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column(feature_name) for feature_name in FEATURES_COL]
# ...
linear_regressor = tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=features)
linear_regressor.fit(input_fn=prepare_input, max_steps=MAX_STEPS)
```

However, the model that is built by the regressor is, unexpectedly, bad. Result could be illustrated with the next picture:
[image]

Visualization code(just in case):

```
plt.plot(height_and_weight_df_filtered[WEIGHT_COL], 
         linear_regressor.predict(input_fn=prepare_full_input), 
         color='blue',
         linewidth=3)
```

Here is the same data been given to the LinearRegression class from the scikit-learn:

```
lr_updated = linear_model.LinearRegression()
lr_updated.fit(weight_filtered_reshaped, height_filtered)
```

And the visualization:
[image]

Increasing amount of steps has no effect. I would assume I'm using regressor from the TensorFlow in a wrong way.

[iPython notebook with the code.](https://storage.googleapis.com/stackoverflow-b0noi/Intro%2Bwith%2BTensorFlow.ipynb)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your TF model does indeed work and will get there with enough steps. You need to jack it right up though - 200K showed significant improvement, almost as good as the sklearn default.

I think there are two issues:

1. sklearn looks like it simply solves the equation using ordinary least squares. TF's LinearRegressor uses the [`FtrlOptimizer`](https://www.eecs.tufts.edu/~dsculley/papers/ad-click-prediction.pdf). The paper indicates it is a better choice for very large datasets.
2. The `input_fn` to the model is injecting the whole training set at once, for every step. This is just a hunch, but I suspect that the FtrlOptimizer may do better if it sees batches at a time.

Instead of just changing the number of steps up a couple orders of magnitude, you can also jack the learning rate up on the optimizer (the default is 0.2) and get similarly good results from only 4k steps:

```
linear_regressor = tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor(
    feature_columns=features, 
    optimizer=tf.train.FtrlOptimizer(learning_rate=5.0))
```

Answer (score 0):

I met a similar problem. The solution is to check if your input_fn has enough epoch. The training maybe not converge before iterating over the whole training data several times.